# Squash Merge button not visible

Tags: git, merge

I want to squash my commits before merging my pull request. I have already enabled squash commits in the settings of my repo.

[image]

After making this change I was hoping that the merge button would look something like this

https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/143418/14119749/7756ff60-f5a4-11e5-8597-12dcbb363746.png

but instead I don't see squash commits in my merge button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I have to click the "merge pull request" button and then I got the option to perform the Squash merge.